# GMail IMAP user and id uniqueness

Tags: email, imap, gmail-imap

I have two users, Joe and Jill, on an email where they are both recipients in the to field. Using IMAP and their respective user oauth tokens, I poll GMail and get this email. What fields will be unique to their user and what won't, e.g. will the email's `message_uid` be different for both of them or the same?

Answer (score 1):

The message bodies themselves will be the same. The UID and ID will likely be different, but not necessarily. The message headers will be the same, except for possibly the Received headers.

Answer (score 0):

There is completely reliable way of detecting this. The usual way of dealing with this is to work on unique `Message-Id` header which is *supposed* to be unique, but in real world, you **will** sooner or later came across a pair of messages which are vastly different, yet share the same `Message-Id`.

Tricks like hashing the raw, undecoded message body tend to work as well (or at least until you hit a user who happens to use a mail server which changes the MIME encoding of such a message).